# Load large dataset into crossfilter/dc.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I built a crossfilter with several dimensions and groups to display the data visually using dc.js. The data visualized is bike trip data, and each trip will be loaded in. Right now, there's over 750,000 pieces of data. The JSON file I'm using is 70 mb large, and will only need to grow as I receive more data in the months to come.

So my question is, how can I make the data more lean so it can scale well? Right now it is taking approximately 15 seconds to load on my internet connection, but I'm worried that it will take too long once I have too much data. Also, I've tried (unsuccessfully) to get a progress bar/spinner to display while the data loads, but I'm unsuccessful.

The columns I need for the data are `start_date, start_time, usertype, gender, tripduration, meters, age`. I have shortened these fields in my JSON to `start_date, start_time, u, g, dur, m, age` so the file is smaller. On the crossfilter there is a line chart at the top showing the total # of trips per day. Below that there are row charts for the day of week (calculated from the data), month (also calculated), and pie charts for usertype, gender, and age. Below that there are two bar charts for the start_time (rounded down to the hour) and tripduration (rounded up to the minute).

The project is on GitHub: https://github.com/shaunjacobsen/divvy_explorer (the dataset is in data2.json). I tried to create a jsfiddle but it is not working (likely due to the data, even gathering only 1,000 rows and loading it into the HTML with `<pre>` tags): http://jsfiddle.net/QLCS2/

Ideally it would function so that only the data for the top chart would load in first: this would load quickly since it's just a count of data by day. However, once it gets down into the other charts it needs progressively more data to drill down into finer details. Any ideas on how to get this to function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend shortening all of your field names in the JSON to 1 character (including "start_date" and "start_time"). That should help a little bit. Also, make sure that compression is turned on on your server. That way the data sent to the browser will be automatically compressed in transit, which should speed things up a ton if it's not already turned on.

For better responsiveness, I'd also recommend first setting up your Crossfilter (empty), all your dimensions and groups, and all your dc.js charts, then using Crossfilter.add() to add more data into your Crossfilter in chunks. The easiest way to do this is to divide your data up into bite-sized chunks (a few MBs each) and load them serially. So if you are using d3.json, then start the next file load in the callback of the previous file load. This results in a bunch of nested callbacks, which is a bit nasty, but should allow the user interface to be responsive while the data is loading.

Lastly, with this much data I believe you will start running into performance issues in the browser, not just while loading the data. I suspect you are already seeing this and that the 15 second pause you are seeing is at least partially in the browser. You can check by profiling in your browser's developer tools. To address this, you'll want to profile and identify performance bottlenecks, then try to optimize those. Also - be sure to test on slower computers if they are in your audience.

Comment: Thank you Ethan. This will be a good performance fix for now but I'm going to need to find something for the longer-term where I'll be displaying many more months' worth of data. I'm definitely already running into slower performance in the browser, outside loading the data.

Comment: Just to get a feel for it, how many trips per month are we talking about here?

Comment: There were roughly 750,000 from July-December. I'd anticipate at least 1 million trips every 6 months.

Comment: It's really on the edge. It should be workable if you are meticulous about keeping your keys and values to the absolute minimum whenever possible. But yes, eventually you'll probably need to look at pre-aggregating server-side and not offering as many dimensions to view/filter on the client side.

Comment: It will be easier to offer fewer dimensions. I can get this down to a few thousand rows if it is only trips per day, gender, age, and user type. But it's the hour and duration that makes the file large. I'll have to search for a solution to getting only the filtered data to load for those dimensions.

Comment: Right. The issue is that Crossfilter needs all the data to be available client-side as far as I'm aware. So there's not really a great solution for the moment. What if you rounded your start times to the nearest hour and your durations/distances to the nearest 10 minutes and 100 meters? Would that help much?

Comment: I have already rounded start times to the start hour, because minute details aren't important. Same with meters = they've been converted to miles and rounded. But the duration is more important (this is for a bike share system where the time limit is 30 minutes) so I have to keep that at minutes.

Comment: Boy am I glad I found this thread - took a few google permutations... Please keep us updated on your progress – I have the exact same issue - 1M records, 8 dimensions. Did the chunking work out for you? If not, what did?

Comment: @o-o I haven't solved the issue yet because a new dataset hasn't been released yet. What I'm planning is to do a datepicker à la Google Analytics if the data gets too slow to load.

Comment: Is json a requirement ? CSV takes less space than json.

Comment: How are you drawing the graphs? If your using an DOM like SVG, throw it out and use canvas with the canvas or webgl api to render for massive pref improvements.

Comment: BTW, I put together a site to serve as an example of doing dynamic server-side pre-aggregation depending on the dimensions selected for viewing on the client-side. It's open source, so you can look at how it was done. Hope to be able to take some of the pieces of this and release them as a toolkit eventually. http://lcadata.info

Answer (score 2):

Consider my class design. It doesn't match yours but it illustrates my points.

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    public List<MyDatum> Data { get; set; }
}

public class MyDatum
{
    public long StartDate { get; set; }
    public long EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The start and end dates are Unix timestamps and the duration is in seconds.

Serializes to:
    "{"Data":
    [{"StartDate":1441256019,"EndDate":1441257181,
    "Duration":451,"Title":"Rad is a cool word."}, ...]}"

One row of datum is 92 chars.

Let's start compressing!
Convert dates and times to base 60 strings.
Store everything in an array of an array of strings.

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    public List<List<string>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Serializes to:
    "{"Data":[["1pCSrd","1pCTD1","7V","Rad is a cool word."],...]}"

One row of datum is now 47 chars.
moment.js is a good library for working with dates and time. It has functions built in to unpack the base 60 format.

Working with an array of arrays will make your code less readable so add comments to document the code.

Load just the most recent 90 days. Zoom to 30 days. When the user drags the brush on the range chart left start fetching more data in chunks of 90 days until the user stops dragging. Add the data to the existing crossfilter using the add method.

As you add more and more data you will notice that your charts get less and less responsive. That is because you have rendered hundreds or even thousands of elements in your svg. The browser is getting crushed. Use the d3 quantize function to group data points into buckets. Reduce the displayed data to 50 buckets.

Quantizing is worth the effort and is the only way you can create a scalable graph with a continuously growing dataset.

Your other option is to abandon the range chart and group the data month over month, day over day, and hour over hour. Then add a date range picker. Since your data would be grouped by month, day, and hour you'll find that even if you rode your bike every hour of the day you'd never have a result set larger than 8766 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I've observed similar issues with data (working in enterprise company), I found couple of ideas worth trying.

1. your data have regular structure, so you can put keys in first row, and only data in following rows - imitating CSV (header first, data next)
2. Date Time can be changed to epoch number (and you can move start of epoch to 01/01/2015 and calculate when received
3. use oboe.js when getting response from server (http://oboejs.com/), as data-set will be large, consider using oboe.drop during load
4. update visualization with JavaScript timer

timer sample

```
var datacnt=0;
var timerId=setInterval(function () {
    // body...
    d3.select("#count-data-current").text(datacnt);
    //update visualization should go here, something like dc.redrawAll()...
},300);

oboe("relative-or-absolute path to your data(ajax)")
.node('CNT',function (count,path) {
    // body...
    d3.select("#count-data-all").text("Expecting " + count + " records");
    return oboe.drop;
})
.node('data.*', function (record, path) {
    // body...
    datacnt++;
    return oboe.drop;
})
.node('done', function (item, path) {
    // body...
    d3.select("#progress-data").text("all data loaded");
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    d3.select("#count-data-current").text(datacnt);
});
```

data sample

```
{"CNT":107498, 
 "keys": "DATACENTER","FQDN","VALUE","CONSISTENCY_RESULT","FIRST_REC_DATE","LAST_REC_DATE","ACTIVE","OBJECT_ID","OBJECT_TYPE","CONSISTENCY_MESSAGE","ID_PARAMETER"], 
 "data": [[22,202,"4.9.416.2",0,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,45],[22,570,"4.9.416.2",0,1449655912,1453867884,-1,"","",0,45],[14,377,"2.102.453.0",-1,1449654863,1468208273,-1,"","",0,45],[14,406,"2.102.453.0",-1,1449654943,1468208477,-1,"","",0,45],[22,202,"10.2.293.0",0,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,8],[22,381,"10.2.293.0",0,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,8],[22,570,"10.2.293.0",0,1449655912,1453867884,-1,"","",0,8],[22,381,"1.80",0,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,41],[22,570,"1.80",0,1449655912,1453867885,-1,"","",0,41],[22,202,"4",0,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,60],[22,381,"4",0,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,60],[22,570,"4",0,1449655913,1453867885,-1,"","",0,60],[22,202,"A20",0,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,52],[22,381,"A20",0,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,52],[22,570,"A20",0,1449655912,1453867884,-1,"","",0,52],[22,202,"20140201",2,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,40],[22,381,"20140201",2,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,40],[22,570,"20140201",2,1449655912,1453867884,-1,"","",0,40],[22,202,"16",-4,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,58],[22,381,"16",-4,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,58],[22,570,"16",-4,1449655913,1453867885,-1,"","",0,58],[22,202,"512",0,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,57],[22,381,"512",0,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,57],[22,570,"512",0,1449655913,1453867885,-1,"","",0,57],[22,930,"I32",0,1449656143,1461122271,-1,"","",0,66],[22,930,"20140803",-4,1449656143,1461122271,-1,"","",0,64],[14,1359,"10.2.340.19",0,1449655203,1468209257,-1,"","",0,131],[14,567,"10.2.340.19",0,1449655185,1468209111,-1,"","",0,131],[22,930,"4.9.416.0",-1,1449656143,1461122271,-1,"","",0,131],[14,1359,"10.2.293.0",0,1449655203,1468209258,-1,"","",0,13],[14,567,"10.2.293.0",0,1449655185,1468209112,-1,"","",0,13],[22,930,"4.9.288.0",-1,1449656143,1461122271,-1,"","",0,13],[22,930,"4",0,1449656143,1461122271,-1,"","",0,76],[22,930,"96",0,1449656143,1461122271,-1,"","",0,77],[22,930,"4",0,1449656143,1461122271,-1,"","",0,74],[22,930,"VMware ESXi 5.1.0 build-2323236",0,1449656143,1461122271,-1,"","",0,17],[21,616,"A20",0,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,135],[21,616,"4",0,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,139],[21,616,"12",0,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,138],[21,616,"4",0,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,140],[21,616,"2",0,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,136],[21,616,"512",0,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,141],[21,616,"Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter",0,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,109],[21,616,"4.4.5.100",0,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,97],[21,616,"3.2.7895.0",-1,1449073850,1449073850,-1,"","",0,56],[9,2029,"10.7.220.6",-4,1470362743,1478315637,1,"vmnic0","",1,8],[9,1918,"10.7.220.6",-4,1470362728,1478315616,1,"vmnic3","",1,8],[9,1918,"10.7.220.6",-4,1470362727,1478315616,1,"vmnic2","",1,8],[9,1918,"10.7.220.6",-4,1470362727,1478315615,1,"vmnic1","",1,8],[9,1918,"10.7.220.6",-4,1470362727,1478315615,1,"vmnic0","",1,8],[14,205,"934.5.45.0-1vmw",-50,1465996556,1468209226,-1,"","",0,47],[14,1155,"934.5.45.0-1vmw",-50,1465996090,1468208653,-1,"","",0,14],[14,963,"934.5.45.0-1vmw",-50,1465995972,1468208526,-1,"","",0,14],
 "done" : true}
```

sample of changing keys first to full array of objects

```
    //function to convert main data to array of objects
    function convertToArrayOfObjects(data) {
        var keys = data.shift(),
            i = 0, k = 0,
            obj = null,
            output = [];

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            obj = {};

            for (k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                obj[keys[k]] = data[i][k];
            }

            output.push(obj);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

this function above works with a bit modified version of data
sample here

```
   [["ID1","ID2","TEXT1","STATE1","DATE1","DATE2","STATE2","TEXT2","TEXT3","ID3"],
    [14,377,"2.102.453.0",-1,1449654863,1468208273,-1,"","",0,45],
    [14,406,"2.102.453.0",-1,1449654943,1468208477,-1,"","",0,45],
    [22,202,"10.2.293.0",0,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,8],
    [22,381,"10.2.293.0",0,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,8],
    [22,570,"10.2.293.0",0,1449655912,1453867884,-1,"","",0,8],
    [22,381,"1.80",0,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,41],
    [22,570,"1.80",0,1449655912,1453867885,-1,"","",0,41],
    [22,202,"4",0,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,60],
    [22,381,"4",0,1449655906,1453867875,-1,"","",0,60],
    [22,570,"4",0,1449655913,1453867885,-1,"","",0,60],
    [22,202,"A20",0,1449655898,1453867824,-1,"","",0,52]]
```

Also consider using memcached https://memcached.org/ or redis https://redis.io/ to cache data at server side, as per data size, redis might get you further